# Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key was converted to an unknown member because the attribute key was not found

Tags: ssas

I got this error when processing the cube.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key was converted to an unknown member because the attribute key was not found

But I set the Dimension and attribute Null Processing properties to Unknown Member, which means it should not fail, but consider it to be unknown.

Why am I still getting the error?

Answer (score 3):

1. Try processing the Dimension first and then the entire cube.
2. Look out for converting the NULLs in the domain of key values to a 'default record' i.e. -1 etc.

Hope this helps.